# Print element of an object in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arrayobject

Print elements from object.
Ex.

```
const emps = {
    "Jacobs": ["Emiel", "Svjetlana", "Ivanna"],
    "Ivanna": ["Michael", "Lawson"],
    "Emiel": ["John", "Ruby"],    
    "Lawson": [],
    "Michael": ["Lindsay", "Ferguson"],
    "Ferguson": []
}
```

In above example lets suppose "Jacob" is Parent of "Emiel", "Svjetlana", "Ivanna", so we have to print sequence "Jacob" "Emiel", "Svjetlana", "Ivanna" means first Parent then childs.

```
Output should be: 
"Jacob" 
"Emiel"
"Svjetlana"
"Ivanna"
"Emiel"
"John"
"Ruby"
"Ivanna"
"Michael"
"Lawson"
"Michael"
"Lindsay"
"Ferguson"
```

Comment: So what is the input to your function? Seems odd it would have the names multiple times in the output. So have you attempted to at least reference the object key and loop over the array?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```js
const emps = {
  "Jacobs": ["Emiel", "Svjetlana", "Ivanna"],
  "Ivanna": ["Michael", "Lawson"],
  "Emiel": ["John", "Ruby"],
  "Lawson": [],
  "Michael": ["Lindsay", "Ferguson"],
  "Ferguson": []
}

const empsArr = Object.entries(emps)
const empsParents = Object.keys(emps)
const firstChildren = empsArr.map(arr =>
  arr[1][0]
)
let leftParents = empsParents.filter(item => item !== empsParents[0]);

const result = empsArr.reduce((acc) => {
  const firstChild = acc.firstChild;
  // if has children add it and its children
  if (emps[firstChild] ?.length > 0) {
    leftParents = leftParents.filter(item => item !== firstChild);
    return {
      res: [...acc.res, firstChild, ...emps[firstChild]],
      firstChild: emps[firstChild][0]
    }
  } else {
    // if has no children move on to the item which has not already been added and is not the first child of any item
    const newParent = leftParents.find(pName => !firstChildren.includes(pName))
    leftParents = leftParents.filter(item => item !== newParent)
    if (emps[newParent]) {
      const newParentData = emps[newParent].length > 0 ? [newParent, ...emps[newParent]] : []
      const firstChildData = typeof emps[firstChild] !== "undefined" ? [firstChild] : []
      const newFirstChild = emps[newParent][0];
      return {
        res: [...acc.res, ...newParentData, ...firstChildData],
        firstChild: newFirstChild
      }
    } else
      return acc
  }
}, {
  res: [
    empsParents[0], ...emps[empsParents[0]]
  ],
  firstChild: emps[empsParents[0]][0]
})
result.res.map(item=>console.log(`"${item}"`))
```

Comment: You didn't read the question closely enough.

Comment: edited the answer, see if this is what you wanted?

Comment: Look at the output and see if you can follow the logic from the input to get there. It starts off with Jacob, and then prints his "children". Then starting with the first child "Emiel", it prints his children, and then from the first child...etc. So a little more complicated.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed that, just edited the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```js
const emps = {
    "Jacobs": ["Emiel", "Svjetlana", "Ivanna"],
    "Ivanna": ["Michael", "Lawson"],
    "Emiel": ["John", "Ruby"],    
    "Lawson": [],
    "Michael": ["Lindsay", "Ferguson"],
    "Ferguson": []
}

function print(obj) {
    for(let x in obj) {
        console.log(x);
        obj[x].forEach(val => console.log(val));
    }
}

print(emps);
```

Comment: They want the first child of the current item to be printed next. It should start off with Jacob, and print his children. Then starting with the first child of Jacob which is "Emiel", it should print Emiel's children,...